# Using classes from the trunk in the branch in Subversion

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, svn, version-control

I am learning how to use Tortoise SVN client and Subversion server.

I understand the concept of a branch, however I have a question.  Say I have a project that contains one thousand classes and all one thousand classes are required to run the project. I want to make a significant change to two of those classes, then do I have to checkout the entire project to the branch? or is it possible to use 998 classes from the trunk and two classes from the branch?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to make a significant change to two of those classes, then do I have to checkout the entire project to the branch?

**Yes and no**

- Yes, **all files of you project** must be in branch
- No, you haven't to checkout all files from branch into new Working Copy

**Explanation**

- You prepare branch as server-side copy of trunk into branch-URL
- When and if you have Working Copy of trunk, you can switch your WC to created branch
- Edit and commit to branch needed changes
  ...
- Merge branch into trunk

Initial Branching

- Using Repo-Browser:

  - Start repo-browser with needed repository
  - Select trunk in tree side
  - "Copy" in Context-menu
  - Define target for "Copy to" (.../branches/SOMENAME-OF-BRANCH)

[image: Copy in Repo-Browser]

- Using local Working Copy of trunk

[image: WC1]

and in dialogue

[image: WC2]

(note "From URL")

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand what you mean by: "You prepare branch as server-side copy of trunk into branch-URL".  Could you elaborate?

Comment: @w0051977 - some screenshots added

Comment: Thanks.  +1.  Before I mark tick your answer - would you ever split a DLL as per thedrs answer below?

Comment: @w0051977 - no, I'll prefer lazy way: rebuild one DLL after change or just the whole app. It's not a question of version control, but builder (and habits)

Comment: Thanks. Finally, do you have multiple trunks on the go or is it one trunk per developer?

Comment: @w0051977 - one **branch per developer** in worst case, but prefer "branch per task" (for any team-size) workflow

Comment: ,thanks.  This is what would work best for me (single developer).  I assume that you have multiple branches on the go that you are working on? (last question).

Comment: @w0051977 - yes, "more than single task in hands" happens (sometimes - not sometimes)^ I just perform cross-branch merges for syncing codebase in such case

Comment: Finally (I promise), would you create a repository per project or per solution? A solution can contain many projects.

Comment: @w0051977 - "It depends". If project can (will) be re-used or it's entity, not "just separated code" it may be separate repo (for the cost of externals overhead). If project have not own value - it will be part of monolithic project. And any repository can be merged|splitted later in process of development

Answer (score 0):

Generally you need all the project files in the branch so the short answer is yes, you need to have them all under the branch.

But, I recommend you split you project and use libraries (DLLs), so that in your case, you can group the 998 classes in one DLL and leave that project under the trunk and just take the changed files project to be branched.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you do this? i.e. change the physical structure of your project just for source control?

Comment: Not just for the source control, but for modularity. It doesn't have to be separating just the changed files, you can take a logical group of file that contains the changed ones and separate it into a module. It is generally best practice to divide your programs into components - it helps maintainability and scalability later on.